# Plugin-Container For Firefox Is Missing In Task Manager?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

After I restarted Firefox (**3.6.15**) I enabled all plugins back and found out that the plugin-container in the Task Manager is missing, but all plugins are working.

How can these plugins work without the plugin-container? Why is the plugin-container missing?

Answer (score 1):

`plugin-container` is *not* supposed to be shown in the taskbar. The only location you are supposed to see the helper process is Task Manager.

Comment: And also only after you've loaded a web page that uses a plugin.

Comment: Sorry i meant Task Manager, not Taskbar.